# JQuery call ajax loaded function in IE

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

In one of my projects I'm using simplemodal to load a dialog that contains a function setup_dialog(). I use the simplemodal callback onShow() to execute setup_dialog(). This functions perfectly in Firefox. But in IE I get an error about setup_dialog() not existing. 
Is this a known limitation of IE (hard to believe) and what can I do to fix it?

The code fails in all versions of IE

My code that shows the dialog

```
$.modal(data, { onShow: function(dialog) { setup_dialog(); });
```

The code in the ajax loaded dialog:

```
function setup_dialog() { // dialog script here }
```

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: post up your existing codes so that we can understand better.

Comment: Which IE version. Post code or link to a sample page where you show the code

Comment: In addition to Kobi's answer...  
What do you mean by "a dialog that contains a function"? Where is the function defined in the first place.  
I can't see how something this elementary would break in IE, please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a simple syntax error - you open two curly braces, but closed only one:

```
$.modal(
    data, { 
       onShow: function(dialog) { setup_dialog(); }
    } //Missing!
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the culprit was an extra  tag at the end of my page.

I can't believe IE would trip over something that trivial. Granted the syntax was flawed but common :(

Either way, thank you all for your help and answers!